# как сделать вывод постов wordpress отдельно на каждой странице?

Tags: php, wordpress

как сделать вывод постов wordpress отдельно на каждой странице?
На главной есть пост с картинкой и кратким описанием, по клику на него переход с полным текстом поста. А так я перехожу по ссылке и всё остается также.

Вывожу новые статьи в index.php, после клика на пост, другие записи исчезают (т.к я перешел по клику по записи). Мне нужно чтобы был анонс записи (до 55 символов-что сделал в index.php). По клику уже на запись чтобы всё было развернуто и текс не обрезан

`<article class="article">
      <h3 class="article__title">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
      <span class="article__date">
        <?php the_date('d.m.Y') ?>
      </span>
      </h3>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', 'class=article__img'); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>

      <footer class="article__footer">
        <div class="tags">
          <?php the_tags('<span>Теги:</span> '); ?>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </article>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно подробности?

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Попробуй почитать документацию по структуре шаблонов WP

Comment: так себе совет, можно на любой вопрос ответить читай документацию/инструкцию. читал на кодексе, там слишком обобщенно.ну хотя бы ссылку отправьте из документации, именно связанную с данным вопросом

Comment: @Stepan Ivanov для этого надо понять суть вопроса. А с таким описанием - это проблематично. Я бы не сказал, что документация WP слишком обобщенно написана.

Comment: @РашенБеар дополнил более подробно

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.8C_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.88.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B

Comment: single.php или page.php отвечает за вывод отдельной записи. Смотря что за запись - страница или именно запись

Comment: @РашенБеар запись нужна в роли статьи для блога. А вообще да - запись. Создается через админку Записи-Добавить новую. В таком случае какой файл рекомендуется и как их связать??

Comment: @РашенБеар создал single php теперь переходит на пустую страницу. Скиньте, пожалуйста, хотя бы полезную статьи как их связать

Comment: @Stepan Ivanov так в него еще шаблон желательно запихнуть

Comment: @РашенБеар у меня есть шаблон, сверстанная страница. верстку уже посадил на вордпресс. если я правильно понял вас

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто. Нужно создать single.php и в него вставить такой код `<?php get_header() ?>
<?php
global $more;
while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $more = 1; // отображаем полностью всё содержимое поста
    the_title(); // эта функция выводит заголовок
    the_content(); // выводим контент
endwhile;
?>
<?php get_footer() ?>`

Подключили необходимые части страницы и проверили в цикле есть ли пост, позже отобразив его содержимое